# Какой командой можно проверить, есть ли в компьютере файлы?

Tags: java

нужна команда(ы), которые смогут проверить, есть ли ф указаном пути, файлы, разных расшрений, или просто, чтобы по имени файлов нашло их

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно получить список файлов в папке

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File root = new File("D:\\SomeFolder");
    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (files[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println(files[i].getName());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: cпасибо большое,дальше через equals сделаю

Comment: @Gokor8 да без проблем, только подтверди мой ответ)